# "Invalid feature class type" for input feature while using "Locate Features Along Routes"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error, arctoolbox, linear-referencing

I am getting ERROR 000810 (Invalid feature class type) when I add my stream shapefile as an in_routes. That is really weird to me.
[image]

Comment: What parameters did you submit?  The error page says "Depending on the tool used and parameter choices, certain feature classes are expected and others are considered invalid" so we need to know them in order to offer any advice.

Comment: Thank you, I think my stream should be converted to routes. That should be the issue....

Answer (score 3):

Based on the attribute table you have provided, it looks as though you are providing a regular polyline as your route feature. Your input route feature needs to be a **Polyline M**.

[image]

Use the [Create Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Routes/003m00000005000000/) tool to create route features.

Comment: That worked, but I don't know why my output table is empty!!